# laravel elequent problem when i use where() before update()

Tags: sql, laravel

In laravel 8 and elequent when i use where() before update() initialize condition ereased!

for example;

```
$post = Post::find($id);
$post->update(['status' => 'published']);
```

this update query is:

```
update `posts` set `status` = 'published' where `id`='1'
```

but when i use where():

```
$post = Post::find($id);
$post->where('status', '=', 'unpublished')->update(['status' => 'published']);
```

update query is:

```
update `posts` set `status` = 'published' where `status`='unpublished'
```

But I expect it to be like the following

```
update `posts` set `status` = 'published' where `status`='unpublished' and `id`='1'
```

Why is the query like this? Is my expectation wrong? or is bug?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using `where` on  a `Collection` instead of building a new query.

If you want to update the current `$post` with a specific value of an attribute you need to use `if` instead.

```
$post = Post::find($id);

if ($post->status == 'unpublished')
    $post->update(['status' => 'published']);
```

Comment: `$post = Post::find($id);` dont return collection, its important for me condition check from sql not with code